# Windows 7, launch a program on windows startup, or when the program is closed

Tags: c#, windows, startup

I am creating a program which by design will need to launch over the top of other programs, and will need to launch on windows startup. The program will also need to relaunch when closed.

I have already looked online and found a folder where I can place my program .exe to launch it on startup, however I was wondering if there was an easier approach that can automatically detect when the program is not open and launch it?

This behaviour would automatically launch the program on startup.

My target OS will be Windows 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What kind of “a program”? This sounds like a Windows service or device driver.

Comment: I am making a windows form application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Task Scheduler to accomplish this. It is a "poor man's service" in the Windows environment. If you need to set up an application like a service this method is *very* easy to do and you'll generally be happy with it.

For your requirements, I would make sure to choose these options:

"Begin the task:"

```
At startup
```

"If the task is already running, then the following rule applies:

```
Do not start a new instance
```

If the task fails, restart every:

```
1 minute
```